# how to save android application's global data to SavedSate

Tags: android

we all know how to save an Activity's state to SavedState via  onSaveInstanceState before it is killed.  but when the application has some global data will be used by all the activities. so I do not have a good method to save the global data. when the application be killed on the backgound.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider storing the data in the shared preferences. This data will persist across the activites. check this [using shared preferences.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)